# Make EXIF Tool Replace Original File

Tags: c#, exif, exiftool

I'm using the EXIF Tool to Copy all the EXIF Tags using the following command

```
exiftool -TagsFromFile file1 file2
```

But if a file named file2 already exists in the source folder, I need the EXIF Tool to replace it.Currently, it is renaming the file as `_orginal`

How can I do this?

Comment: what language of programming or where do you use the command windows console, linux console etc.?

Comment: What do you want to replace ``file2``, which is your input file, with?

Comment: @AdisakAnusornsrirung In windows 'cmd'

Comment: @J.N. file1 is the input file,file 2 is the output file .. i have just specified the syntax.If file1.FileName=file2.FileName then file2 should be replaced..instead of making a copy of the original.

Comment: If you are using this version of ``exiftool`` (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html), it looks like you'll have to use the ``-o`` flag to designate ``file2`` as being your output file.

Comment: @J.N. So i guess `exiftool -o -TagsFromFile file1 file2`

Comment: That won't work... try reading about the command line, and how to use parameters: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_learning_the_shell.php (This one is a Linux tutorial, but the principle of passing parameters is the same on Windows)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the `-overwrite_original` option to your exiftool command

Comment: Thanks for answering this Phil,sorry i responded late.Btw you have a great Tool :)